# How to download big file & resume download after interuption in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I wrote an app that downloads big zip files and extracts them using **request** and **unzipper**. I've also managed to show downloading progress but the requirement is that it has to be able to resume download after an interuption (internet goes down or the app closes, *for example how steam downloads games) and i cant figure it out, my code is kinda like this

```
const getInstallerFile = (installerfileURL, installerfilename, Possition, Directory) => {

// Variable to save downloading progress
var received_bytes = 0;
var total_bytes = 0;
percentage = 0;
var outStream = fs.createWriteStream(installerfilename);

request
    .get(installerfileURL)
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log("Download has stopped", err);
    })
    .on('response', function (data) {
        total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
        console.log("download has started")

    })
    .on('data', function (chunk) {
  //gets percentage after every chunk
        received_bytes += chunk.length;
        showDownloadingProgress(received_bytes, total_bytes, Possition);
    })
    .pipe(outStream)
    outStream.on('finish', function () {
    console.log("download has completed")
//...codeblock for storing local data

    fs.createReadStream(installerfilename)
        .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: Directory }))
        .on('finish', function () {
            console.log("unzipper finished extracting")
    //deleting the zip after downloading
            fs.rmSync(installerfilename, { recursive: true, force: true });

        });


})

};
```

is it even possible to resume download using request or even node in general?

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? If so could you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible to do. When creating the subsequent request you will have to read the file size of the half-downloaded file and make a partial request for those missing bytes. But the server should be setup to handle partial requests as well.

To read the filesize of the half-downloaded file you can use node's fs.promise.stat(PATH), get the file size and inserted it as the startRange.

```js
const startRange = 4000;
const endRange = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

const response = await request(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept-Ranges': 'arraybuffer',
        "Response-Type": 'arraybuffer',
        "Range": `bytes=${startRange}-${endRange},`
    }
});
```